# matplotlib: value error x and y have different dimensions

Tags: matplotlib

Having some difficulty plotting out values grouped by a text/name field and along a range of dates.  The issue is that while I can group by the name and generate plots for some of the date ranges, there are instances where the grouping contains missing date values (just the nature of the overall dataset).

That is to say, I may very well be able to plot for a date_range('10/1/2013', '10/31/2013') for SOME of the grouped values, but there are instances where there is no '10/15/2013' within that range and therefore will throw  the error mentioned in the title of this post.

Thanks for any input!

```
plt.rcParams['legend.loc'] = 'best'

  dtable = pd.io.parsers.read_table(str(datasource), sep=',')
  unique_keys = np.unique(dtable['KEY'])

  index = date_range(d1frmt, d2frmt)
  for key in unique_keys:

      values = dtable[dtable['KEY'] == key]

      plt.figure()

      plt.plot(index, values['VAL']) <--can fail if index is missing a date

      plt.xlim(xmin=d1frmt,xmax=d2frmt)
      plt.xticks(rotation=270)
      plt.xticks(size='small')
      plt.legend(('H20'))
      plt.ylabel('Head (ft)')
      plt.title('Well {0}'.format(key))
      fig =  str('{0}.png'.format(key))

      out = str(outputloc) + "\\" + str(fig)

      plt.savefig(out)
      plt.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **must** have a date column, or index, in your dtable. Otherwise you dont know which in `values['Val']` belong to which date.

If you do, there are two ways.

Since you make a subset based on a key, you can either use the index (if its a datetime!) of that subset:

```
plt.plot(values.index.to_pydatetime(), values['VAL'])
```

or reindex the subset to your 'target' range":

```
values = values.reindex(index)
plt.plot(index.to_pydatetime(), values['VAL'])
```

By default, reindex inserts NaN values as missing data.

It would be easier if you gave a working example, its a bit hard to answer without knowing what your Dataframe looks like.

Comment: oooh, this looks promising. Thank you for your input and example! Yes, there is a datetime column -- the .csv datasource includes: 'KEY', 'DATEREAD', and 'VAL'.  I will give your suggestion a try this morning.

Comment: Thanks again for your input RK.  I was able to get some of your suggestions implemented.  It turns out that much of the problems I was encountering along the way was due to some strange formatting of the values when things were being written/read to a .csv file.  Most of my issues resolved themselves by simply using the DataFrames themseleves.  Also, if I simply changed the source data to consist of NaN's then all plots perfectly!